# Relation between DISTSTYLE and Compression encoding in Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Is there any relation between DISTSTYLE and Compression encoding in Redshift. As whenever we use Compression encoding the operating system on compute node do extra work of encoding and decoding the data; with DISTSTYLE set as ALL don't you thing every node had to do the decoding and encoding work ?

Any conceptual help here is highly appreciated.

Comment: Not an issue you need to worry about but... Compression actually makes access faster in most circumstance, as SSD (or HDD depending on instance type) speed can be the bottleneck. Compression technology makes sure that encoding/decoding is fast & likely has hardware on chip to do some of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Distribution Style determines which node/slice** will store the data. This has no relationship or impact on compression type. It is simply saying *where* to store the data.

Compression, however, is closely related to the **Sort Key**, which determines the *order* in which data is stored. Some compression methods use 'offsets' from previous values, or even storing the number of *repeated* values, which can significantly compress data (eg "repeat this value 1000 times" rather than storing 1000 values).

Compression within Amazon Redshift has two benefits:

- Less storage space (thus, less cost)
- More data can be retrieved for each disk access

The slowest operation of *any* database is disk access. Therefore, any reduction in disk access will speed operations. The time taken to decompress data is minor compared to the time required for an additional disk read operation.

The second most 'expensive' operation is sending data between nodes. While network traffic is faster than disk access, it is best avoided.

When using `DISTSTYLE ALL`, it simply means that the data is available on every node, which avoids the need to transfer data across the network.